# How to link external library (.lib) from 3rd party into UEFI application? (by EDK2)

Tags: c, visual-c++, makefile, uefi

I have EDK II (UDK2014) application and I need to link one LIB file from 3rd party.
I tried to add "BuildOptions" in my app INF file:

```
[BuildOptions]
  MSFT:*_*_X64_SLINK_FLAGS = /LIBPATH:"$(WORKSPACE)\ShellAppPkg\MyApp" "Test.lib"
```

But it still didn't work. The error message is:

```
MyApp.lib:<Test1.obj> : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol xxxxx
```

It seemed that "lib.exe" command didn't work properly. I tried to change LIB file name and the result was the same.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for my toolchain.

Comment: If that external library is using hosted standard C (.e.g. uses C standard library functions à la `malloc` or `printf`), it probably won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Basile. The LIB file I included was not for UEFI. I tried to build one  standard C Library and it can be linked now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this in your INF file:

```
[binaries.IA32]
 LIB | MyFancyLib.lib   

[binaries.X64]
 LIB | MyFancyLib64.lib
```

Comment: Hi CodeRush, it seems that these options didn't work on my build environment after I got UEFI available LIB file. Thanks anyway.